# Using an object as a mask

Tags: color, mask

I have a black object in a layer all by itself that I'm trying trying to use as a mask, to cut out a white object the same size.

[image: object I'm trying to turn white]

I tried drawing an white rectangle on a new layer, placed it on top of the black item layer, selected "Create Clipping Mask", and nothing happened.

What's the best way to do achieve this goal? I tried selecting the image by color, and using the brush tool to paint it white, but the results are unprofessional.

[image: attempt no. 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the same object of different color then you can use blending option

Steps

1. Select your layer and Double click on it(or Right Click > Blending Options)
2. From The layer style dialog box check Color Overlay and select your color

[image]

That's it you dont need to do any thing else